# C++ Skipping the rest of the current `for` iteration and beginning a new one. 

Tags: c++, for-loop

Consider this C++ code

```
for(int i=0; i<=N; ++i)

{

if(/* Some condition 1 */) {/*Blah Blah*/}

if(/* Some condition 2  */){/*Yadda Yadda*/}

}
```

Is there any keyword/command so that if condition 1 evaluates to `true` and execution of `/*Blah Blah*/` I can skip the rest of the current iteration and begin a new iteration by incrementing `i`.

The closest thing I know to this kind of statement skipping is `break` but that terminates the loop entirely.

I guess one could do this by using some flags and if statements, but a simple keyword would be very helpful.

Comment: You should read a book from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) list.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the keyword `continue` and it will 'continue' to the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: So in this case I should use `continue` at the tail-end of the `/*Blah Blah*/` statements,  correct?

Comment: Correct. You place `continue;` at whatever point in the flow you want it to move on to the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: I `#define skip continue` in my main header file. `skip` then becomes a synonym for `continue` and it means to "skip" a loop iteration, (and hence `continue` on with the next)

Answer (score 5):

This case seems better suited for if..**else**.. than a continue, although continue would work fine.

```
for(int i=0; i<=N; ++i)
{
    if(/* Some condition 1 */)
    {/*Blah Blah*/}
    else if(/* Some condition 2  */)
    {/*Yadda Yadda*/}
}
```

Comment: Oh yes! How stupid of me :D Thank you. God knows what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Continue` statement, stops the current loop and continues to the next, rather than breaking altogether

[Continue](http://www.google.com.ng/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCAQFjAB&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e3dc2z3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx&ei=Fa97TtO-K8eA4gT87sTSDw&usg=AFQjCNH8gi9yD8F_Q7DAgLJwHXoYQAXsJA)